# Activate debugging mode for sssd service

Tags: linux, debugging, sssd

I encountred a problem when I restarted sssd service:

```
Stopping sssd: cat: /var/run/sssd.pid: No such file or directory [FAILED]
Starting sssd:                                                   [FAILED]
```

So i need to activat the debug mode to understand what's happen with sssd service

any suggestion!!

Comment: how are you restarting it ? I remember running into this problem and using `service sssd restart` and never getting problem again

Comment: `service sssd restart`, but that was before figuring out that the problem comes from a bad configuration of : /etc/krb5.conf

Answer (score 0):

Please set debug_level=N in sssd.conf's concerned section and restart service. you can see logs in /var/log/sssd directory.

N is a number between 1 and 10 into the particular section.

I use Level 6 for debugging problems.